# Dynamically generating Update Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update, nullable, isnull

I've written following stored procedure which dynamically creates one update statement to update **Product** table with the respective values fetched from **Rule1** and **Rule2** tables on certain join conditions.

The problem I'm facing is that when I'm comparing original **Product** table values with the values coming from joins, then the **update Query** is not forming.

The original values which are present in **Product**  table  may or may not be **NULL**. I need to check if the original values are not same then update the corresponding column with the value.

here is the sp code:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateCTFamilyRules]
    AS     
    BEGIN       
        DECLARE @T_1 NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
        DECLARE @T_2 NVARCHAR(100) = NULL   
        DECLARE @Fl NVARCHAR(100) = NULL    

        DECLARE @T1 NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
        DECLARE @T2 NVARCHAR(100) = NULL    
        DECLARE @F NVARCHAR(100) = NULL 

    Select  @T_1 = p.T1, 
            @T_2 = p.T2, 
            @Fl = p.F
    from Product p  
    where p.Manufacturer_Name = 'Dell'; 


    Select  @T1 = r2.T1, 
            @T2 = r2.T2, 
            @F = r2.F
    from Product p
    join Rule1 r1 on p.Product_Code = r1.Product_Code
    join Rule2 r2 on r1.MajorCode = r2.Product_Family
    where p.Manufacturer_Name = 'Dell';         

    BEGIN       
        DECLARE @sqlCommand VARCHAR(8000)       
        DECLARE @Starter VARCHAR(100)

        SET @Starter = 'SET '
        SET @sqlCommand = 'UPDATE Product '

        BEGIN               
            IF ( @T1 IS NOT NULL) AND ( @T1 <> @T_1 )  BEGIN   SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + @Starter + 'T1 = ''' + @T1 + ''''  SET @Starter = ', ' END
            IF ( @T2 IS NOT NULL) AND ( @T1 <> @T_2)  BEGIN   SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + @Starter + 'T2 = ''' + @T2 + ''''  SET @Starter = ', ' END
            IF ( @F IS NOT NULL)  AND ( @F <> @Fl ) BEGIN   SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + @Starter + 'F = ''' + @F + ''''  SET @Starter = ', ' END    
        END

        -- if any one column  get updated in DB then automatically starter sets to , then execute dynamic sqlCommand else ignore..

        IF (@Starter = ', ')
        BEGIN       
            SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + @Starter + ' Last_Modify_Date = ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(22),SYSDATETIME(),121) + '''' 
            SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + ' from Product p
                join Rule1 r1 on p.Product_Code = r1.Product_Code
                join Rule2 r2 on r1.MajorCode = r2.Product_Family 
                WHERE p.Manufacturer_Name = ''' + 'Dell' + ''''         
            EXEC (@sqlCommand)
       END      
    END 
END
```

Kindly let me where this is problem with the comparison I'm doing using nullable column. And if it is then how I can modify it. Thanks.

Comment: Is there only one row for Manufacturer_Name = 'Dell' in Product table ?

Comment: I want to check if the columns T1,T2 and F in original **Product** table are null or have some value. If null or some different value other than what is coming from join then update that column else leave it as it is.

Comment: @Aditya : Yes it'll return multiple records. I need to fetch all such records after join. And then check if the Product table have records null or some different value, if yes then update product table with the fetched values one by one. Do I need cursors to do this?

Comment: please check my answer below. It would be easier approach to satisfy your requirement. Also, if the records returning are multiple, can you assign multiple values to a single variable ?

Comment: Can you please let me know what is wrong with my answer ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [MERGE UPDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb510625.aspx) in SQL Server ?

```
MERGE Prodcut AS TARGET
USING (
        SELECT   R2.Manufacturer_Name, 
                 R2.T1, 
                 R2.T2, 
                 R2.F
        FROM     Product P
                 INNER JOIN Rule1 R1 ON P.Product_Code = R1.Product_Code
                 INNER JOIN Rule2 R2 ON R1.MajorCode = R2.Product_Family
       ) AS SOURCE ( Manufacturer_Name, T1, T2, F ) 
         ON (TARGET.Manufacturer_Name = SOURCE.Manufacturer_Name) -- Match on condition
WHEN MATCHED AND (TARGET.T1 <> SOURCE.T1 OR 
                  TARGET.T2 <> SOURCE.T2 OR 
                  TARGET.F <> SOURCE.F) -- Find non matched columns
THEN 
UPDATE SET   TARGET.T1 = SOURCE.T1, 
             TARGET.T2 = SOURCE.T2, 
             TARGET.F = SOURCE.F -- Update non matched columns
```

***Note: Please test the code on test database & modify as required.***